# How to see web page real time while editing

Tags: html, forms, class, input

How can I see the web page realtime by side to side while editing the web pages in vs code ?

I tried extension of Microsoft edge but it shows a blurred and poor quality of the web page i designed.

Answer (score 1):

use live server extension in vs code...there you can see your real time activity.thank you